# Chrome dev tool workspace: I can't map my network resource?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, prefixfree

I am trying out the new Chrome dev tool workspace.

**Setup:**
I got my wampserver running.
I have chucked in my project files in the wamp folder.
I am using sublime text as my editor.

**Problem:**
All the edits that I am doing on dev tool are reflected in sublime and vice versa.
However I couldn't get the live reload working?

Hence every time I make a new change, the browser isn't picking up the new edit, I will have to refresh my browser.

[image]

---

**Update**

I just found out that if I get rid of the prefixfree script tag, it fixes everything. Not sure why the script tag is screwing up the workspace?

It seems like prefixfree is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I have gotten the Chrome Workspace all up and running.
Indeed, Prefixfree.js is screwing things up.

**My setup:**
1) Get a localhost (I am using WAMP to set it up)
2) Run your project through your localhost eg: localhost/project
3) F12, open chrome dev tools on it, the localhost/project
4) Configure Workspaces to map it back to your system drive